# UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a function that updates existing UICollectionView. 
The UICollectionView is created, I can see it, but when I want to access its cells to update it, they are nil.

```
-(void)finishExam{

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.questionsOverviewCollection numberOfItemsInSection:0]; i++) {

        NSLog(@"self.questionsOverviewCollection - %@",self.questionsOverviewCollection);
        NSLog(@"cell - %@",[self.questionsOverviewCollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]]);
        NSLog(@"overviewCell - %@",(OverviewCell*)[self.questionsOverviewCollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]]);
        NSLog(@"numOfCells - %d", [self.questionsOverviewCollection numberOfItemsInSection:0]);

        OverviewCell *cell = (OverviewCell*)[self.questionsOverviewCollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
            [cell finishExam];
    }
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    OverviewCell *cell = (OverviewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell someSetUp];

    return cell;
}
```

Log:

```
self.questionsOverviewCollection - <UICollectionView: 0xa1abc00; frame = (14 219; 217 441); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xe0617a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xe0bbb00>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0xe0cc3f0>
cell - (null)
overviewCell - (null)
numOfCells - 30
```

Comment: You are getting all cell null or you get some cell and after that u get null?

Comment: Though the answers here work, if you can, it's better to call `[cell finishExam]` directly on your data model instead of proxing through the `collectionView`. See my comment on Paul S.'s answer. In most cases, you should be able to get cell layout information from the `collectionViewLayout` property, and model specific functionality like `- finishExam` should be available on your model, or configured when the cell is dequeued.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/cellForItemAtIndexPath%3a) docs (emphasis my own)

> **Return Value**
>   The cell object at the corresponding index path or **nil if the cell is not visible** or indexPath is out of range.

You should update your underlying model, which provides the data to the views.

Comment: This worked for me, but in addition to reloading the data with [view reloadData], I also had to [view layoutIfNeeded] as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/21480786/1388195

Comment: Calling [collectionView layoutIfNeeded] worked for me to acquire the cell after calling [collectionView reloadData]. Thanks @zyzof

Comment: Thanks all for the layoutIfNeeded!!! :D Just wondering, does anyone know why though? Cause in my case the cell has been visible the entire time.

Comment: Hey @RichardMcCluskey, do you know why we have to call this? I notice that all the UICollectionViews are rendered properly but indeed, without this line of call `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is returning `nil` all the time!

Comment: Hey @zyzof, you should totally post your suggestion as a separate answer!! That works great for me!

Comment: If you 'drag' the cell outside the collection view's frame, it will not be visible.

Comment: Calling `layoutIfNeeded` worked for me. However, I didn't like the explicit need to call that. In my specific use case, I was subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and calling `collectionView.cellForItemAt` in my `layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath:)` implementation. I was able to get all the information for cell layout I needed from `super.layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath)`.

Comment: On iOS 10 and above `nil` from `UICollectionView`'s `cellForItem(at indexPath)` can be caused by prefetching, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322995/uicollectionview-cellforitematindexpath-returns-null-in-ios-10-only-works-fine

Comment: Documentation is not accurate. I fetched the index I'm trying to use in `cellForItem(at:)` directly from my data source. The collection view is just out of sync. `layoutIfNeeded` fixed for me.

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
[collectionView reloadData];
[collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
```