# UICollectionViewCell : Cell is changed while Scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, collections

I am facing some problem with `UICollectionView`. I am storing the original cell in instance variable. check below code.

```
originalCell = (CollectionViewCell *)[_colloctionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:dragIndexPath];
   NSLog(@"Main Cell %@",originalCell);
```

**Console O/P**

```
  Main Cell <CollectionViewCell: 0xdae4fc0; baseClass =
 UICollectionViewCell; frame = (216.5 30; 95 113); clipsToBounds = YES;
 alpha = 0.3; opaque = NO; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0xdae5070>>
```

Now **I am scrolling** then i check the cell object. it gives me like that.

**Console O/P**

```
  ENd <CollectionViewCell: 0xdae4fc0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell;
 frame = (112.5 548.5; 95 113); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag =
 8; layer = <CALayer: 0xdae5070>>
```

As you can see object value is changed now. i think this is the problem of **reauseablity**.

But How can i solve this problem in easy way.
Thanks

Comment: Try to store `NSIndexPath` and use `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: No i have tried.. cellForItemAtIndexPath methd returns nil. same problem like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861804/uicollectionview-cellforitematindexpath-is-nil

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is cell reusability issue, try creating cell identifier like this. It will work.

```
NSString *identifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
```

If you are using custom cell, cell creation code will be changed accordingly.