# iOS: cellForItemAtIndexPath returns nil even though cell is visible

Tags: ios, cocoa, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view and i have implemented drag and drop functionality. In addition, when cell is close to the top or bottom edges i scroll the collection with constant speed.

When i drag the cell i set its transform property according to the gesture and i also modify the value while scrolling. I also change the transform property of the layout attributes for the index path.
The cell is always on the screen in the gesture position. However, at some point the collection decides to hide the cell and cellForItemAtIndexPath return nil.

Why does it happen and how can i prevent this situation?

Comment: Did you try searching in the 'visibleCells' array?

Comment: Yes. the cell is indeed missing

Comment: So, once you start mucking around with the cell, save it in an ivar (so its retained) and also save its index. If the system asks you for the cell of that index, return the one you've retained in the ivar (that's why you need to know the indexPath). Once the drag/drop is completely done, you can then nil the ivar (and saved IndexPath).

Comment: I retrieve the cell using dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier so i think the collection will enqueue it, no? I don't think i could keep using it even it is retained by an ivar

Comment: Right hold onto it don't try to dequeue it. You asked how to solve this I'm telling you how, so try it

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. I have no control over the cell lifecycle

Comment: You don't get it so won't comment again. iOS asks you for the cell you provide it. You can save it - I often do in settings - so you can retain it save it and when asked to provide that cell return the saved object. The do this all the time, for year after year.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem. And I solve it by calling `layoutIfNeeded` following before asking for the reference to the cell.

```
self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

See [cellForItemAtIndexPath returns nil after force scrolling to make it visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469459)