# state restoration working but then nullified in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, state-restoration

*Note code has been updated to incorporate the fixes detailed in the comments, but here is the original question text:*

State restoration works on the code-based ViewController below, but then it is "undone" by a second call to viewDidLoad. My question is: how do I avoid that?
 With a breakpoint at `decodeRestorableState` I can see that it does in fact restore the 2 parameters `selectedGroup` and `selectedType` but then it goes through viewDidLoad again and those parameters are reset to nil so the restoration is of no effect. There's no storyboard: if you associated this class with an empty ViewController it will work (I double checked this -- there are some button assets too, but they aren't needed for function). I've also included at the bottom the AppDelegate methods needed to enable state restoration.

```
import UIKit

class CodeStackVC2: UIViewController, FoodCellDel {

  let fruit = ["Apple", "Orange", "Plum", "Qiwi", "Banana"]
  let veg = ["Lettuce", "Carrot", "Celery", "Onion", "Brocolli"]
  let meat = ["Beef", "Chicken", "Ham", "Lamb"]
  let bread = ["Wheat", "Muffin", "Rye", "Pita"]
  var foods = [[String]]()
  let group = ["Fruit","Vegetable","Meat","Bread"]
  var sView = UIStackView()
  let cellId = "cellId"
  var selectedGroup : Int?
  var selectedType : Int?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    restorationIdentifier = "CodeStackVC2"
    foods = [fruit, veg, meat, bread]
    setupViews()
    displaySelections()
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    guard let index = selectedGroup, let type = selectedType else { return }
    pageControl.currentPage = index
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
    cView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition(), animated: true)
    cView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    guard let cell = cView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? FoodCell else { return }
    cell.pickerView.selectRow(type, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
  }

  //State restoration encodes parameters in this func
  override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    if let theGroup = selectedGroup,
      let theType = selectedType {
      coder.encode(theGroup, forKey: "theGroup")
      coder.encode(theType, forKey: "theType")
    }
    super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
  }

  override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    selectedGroup = coder.decodeInteger(forKey: "theGroup")
    selectedType = coder.decodeInteger(forKey: "theType")
    super.decodeRestorableState(with: coder)
  }

  override func applicationFinishedRestoringState() {
    //displaySelections()
  }

  //MARK: Views
  lazy var cView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 120)
    let cRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 120)
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: cRect, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return cv
  }()

  lazy var pageControl: UIPageControl = {
    let pageC = UIPageControl()
    pageC.numberOfPages = self.foods.count
    pageC.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
    pageC.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
    pageC.backgroundColor = .black
    pageC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changePage(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    return pageC
  }()

  var textView: UITextView = {
    let tView = UITextView()
    tView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
    tView.textColor = .white
    tView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return tView
  }()

  func makeButton(_ tag:Int) -> UIButton{
    let newButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let img = UIImage(named: group[tag])?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    newButton.setImage(img, for: .normal)
    newButton.tag = tag // used in handleButton()
    newButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    newButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    newButton.backgroundColor = .clear
    return newButton
  }
  //Make a 4-item vertical stackView containing
  //cView,pageView,subStackof 4-item horiz buttons, textView
  func setupViews(){
    view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    cView.register(FoodCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    //generate an array of buttons
    var buttons = [UIButton]()
    for i in 0...foods.count-1 {
      buttons += [makeButton(i)]
    }
    let subStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
    subStackView.axis = .horizontal
    subStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    subStackView.alignment = .center
    subStackView.spacing = 20
    //set up the stackView
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [cView,pageControl,subStackView,textView])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 5
    //Add the stackView using AutoLayout
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    cView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
  }

  // selected item returned from pickerView
  func pickerSelection(_ foodType: Int) {
    selectedType = foodType
    displaySelections()
  }

  func displaySelections() {
    if let theGroup = selectedGroup,
      let theType = selectedType {
      textView.text = "\n \n Group: \(group[theGroup]) \n \n FoodType: \(foods[theGroup][theType])"
    }
  }

  // 3 User Actions: Button, Page, Scroll
  func handleButton(sender: UIButton) {
    pageControl.currentPage = sender.tag
    let x = CGFloat(sender.tag) * cView.frame.size.width
    cView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:x, y:0), animated: true)
  }

  func changePage(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
    let x = CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage) * cView.frame.size.width
    cView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:x, y:0), animated: true)
  }

  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let index = Int(cView.contentOffset.x / view.bounds.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(index) //change PageControl indicator
    selectedGroup = Int(index)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
    guard let cell = cView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? FoodCell else { return }
    selectedType =  cell.pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    displaySelections()
  }

  //this causes cView to be recalculated when device rotates
  override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    cView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
  }
}
//MARK: cView extension
extension CodeStackVC2: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return foods.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! FoodCell
    cell.foodType = foods[indexPath.item]
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: textView.frame.height * 0.4)
  }
}

// *********************
protocol FoodCellDel {
  func pickerSelection(_ food:Int)
}

class FoodCell:UICollectionViewCell, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

  var delegate: FoodCellDel?
  var foodType: [String]? {
    didSet {
      pickerView.reloadComponent(0)
      //pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    }
  }

  lazy var pickerView: UIPickerView = {
    let pView = UIPickerView()
    pView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:Int(pView.bounds.width), height:Int(pView.bounds.height))
    pView.delegate = self
    pView.dataSource = self
    pView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    return pView
  }()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
  }

  func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = .clear
    addSubview(pickerView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: pickerView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: pickerView)
  }
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = foodType?.count {
      return count
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
    pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    if let foodItem = foodType?[row] {
      pickerLabel.text = foodItem
      pickerLabel.textColor = .white
      return pickerLabel
    } else {
      print("chap = nil in viewForRow")
      return UIView()
    }
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if let actualDelegate = delegate {
      actualDelegate.pickerSelection(row)
    }
  }

}

extension UIView {
  func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views: UIView...) {
    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
    for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
      let key = "v\(index)"
      view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      viewsDictionary[key] = view
    }
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
  }
}
```

Here are the functions in AppDelegate:

```
  //====if set true, these 2 funcs enable state restoration
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    //replace the storyboard by making our own window
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    //this defines the entry point for our app
    window?.rootViewController = CodeStackVC2()
    return true
  }
```

Comment: I didn't solve anything but: I'm getting a compiler error at this line: `addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: pickerView)` and the next line. I had to change it to `addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["v0" : pickerView]))`. And I see [this](http://imgur.com/a/gV3sj) image. 1. please update your code. 2. Is this image what you expect?

Comment: 3. Even after all these changes I get some warnings in the debugger. I'm wondering if you're getting them as well and ignoring them?! I get "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" and "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint ". See the errors [image](http://imgur.com/a/gV3sj). For a solution on that warning see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html).

Comment: My apologies: I forgot to include an extension. It's now included & I just tested in a fresh project & it worked (except for some button assets, unecessary for function).  So, now the code should work, & the state restoration problem can be demonstrated by 1) running in the simulator of Xcode, 2) making a choice of food group and/or food type (by swiping & using the pickers), 3) going to Home (shift-cmd-H), 4) clicking the stop button to stop it running, and finally 5) running again to see that the state is not restored (or as it says above, IS restored and then that restoration is nullified)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `viewDidLoad` is being called twice it will because your view controller is being created twice.

You do not say how you are creating the view controller but I suspect your problem is that the view controller is being created first by a storyboard or in the app delegate and then a second time because you have set a restoration class.

You only need to set a restoration class if your view controller is not being created by the normal app load sequence (a restoration identifier is enough otherwise). Try removing the line in `viewDidLoad` where you set a restoration class and I think you will see `viewDidLoad` is called once followed by `decodeRestorableState`.

Update: Confirmed you are creating the view controller in the app delegate so you do not need to use a restoration class. That fixes the problem with `viewDidLoad` being called twice.

You want to do the initial root view controller creation in `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the app delegate as that is called before state restoration takes place.

The final issue once you have the selectedGroup and selectedType values restored is to update the UI elements (page control, collection view), etc to use the restored values

Comment: The code for making the viewController is now at the end of my question. I am not using storyboards at all - in fact, based on your response, I even deleted Main.storyboard. When I remove the restoration class, viewDidLoad is only called once, and it also correctly restores the parameters in decodeRestorableState IF I use willFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate instead of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. However, despite this, the state is not in fact restored! And if I use didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, it does not even stop at decodeRestorableState. I just can't get the state to restore!

Comment: So at least we have fixed the issue with viewDidLoad being called twice :-)

You want to do your view controller creation in willFinishLaunchingWithOptions - that is called before state restoration takes place.

What I am not clear about is what state your are trying to save and restore? You will also want to refresh the user interface after state restoration (viewWillAppear is a good place for that)

Comment: To finish my comment above

The code is successfully restoring the values for selectedGroup and selectedType but you then need to update the UI to use the restored values. You have a complex controller that you maybe want to break up but at least once restoration is complete you need to set the page control, scroll the collection view, etc.

Comment: Everything is working now except your last "etc." above! That is, all states are restore properly except for the pickerView found within the collectionView. I put the refresh code into viewDidAppear because it did not work in viewWillAppear. In my updated code, but the second guard statement in viewDidAppear is preventing the pickerView from refreshing, and I can't figure out why. Any help is welcome. THANK YOU very much! You earned the bounty, but I also thank CloakedEddy! I'm surprised how little help is online on this topic in Swift - makes me wonder if people really use state restoration?

Comment: Update: remaining minor problem solved based on the post below (see my swift-based version of an answer there). Not pretty, but it worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469459/cellforitematindexpath-returns-nil-after-force-scrolling-to-make-it-visible/45625494#45625494

Comment: Great, glad you were able to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

In my six years of iOS programming, I don't remember ever seeing iOS calling `viewDidLoad()` twice on the same view controller. So it is most likely that you are instantiating CodeStackVC2 twice :)

As far as I can tell, you are creating the view hierarchy programmatically in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. However, state restoration is invoked *before* this delegate method is called. So, iOS asks the view controller's *restoration class* for a new view controller instance, and after that your code setting up the base hierarchy is executed, creating a fresh view controller.

Try moving your code from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (which is called before any state restoration). Then, since the view controller that iOS is trying to restore already exists, it won't call that method with the long name from the `UIViewControllerRestoration` protocol, and instead call `decodeRestorableState(with coder:)` on that view controller.

If you need a more in-depth explanation, try [useyourloaf](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/state-preservation-and-restoration/) or of course the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html) - I have found both to be very useful in understanding the concepts behind Apple's implementation. Although I must admit, I took me several reads before I understood it myself.

Comment: I tried what you asked, but state restoration still doesn't work. See the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions code from my AppDelegate in my question. I have breakpoints at the last } of both viewDidLoad & decodeRestorableState & when I run & go through the 5 steps (described in my Aug 6 at 19:21 comment) to test state restoration it breaks as follows: viewDidLoad-decodeRestorableState-viewDidLoad.  But when, as you suggest, I put the code in willFinishLaunchingWithOptions (see commented code) it now breaks as follows: viewDidLoad-viewDidLoad-decodeRestorableState  (please see comment to kharrison)

Comment: So even when you setup the starting view hierarchy in `willFinish`, State Restoration still creates a new VC for you. I forgot about this, but the restoration class you supplied *takes precedence* over the existing view controller, and is asked for a new one regardless of an matching existing one (as described in the Apple documentation  ). See what happens when you remove the restoration class.

Comment: I did try removing the restoation class --  as kharrison advised -- and wrote about  it in my comment to him above.